# Font size to large to fit in cache for Emoji on Kitkat Only

Tags: android, opengl-es, textview, emoji

I am trying to use the paint to dynamically change the size of text. I am noticing that when I  have one emoji and allow it to fill a view that opengl throws the error that `Font size to large to fit in cache.`

In other questions people have suggested augmenting the path of the text to render it or to try and turn off hardware acceleration. These don't seem to solve the problem.

I really just need to know how I can tell what the max size is I can display without the size being too large that it won't show.

**Update:**
I have tried using the text paint to see if the text will have enough room to render in the view. So I know that I have the proper size of the view but am still seeing this issue.

**Update 4/15/15:**
I forgot to update my question but I created an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69706) for Android and it has been accepted as an issue. There was a suggestion to use

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

But because there is no callback or way to get a failure from the renderer you would have to always use `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` for your views and not `HARDWARE`.

Comment: Have you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: @chester1000 no unfortunately not. I had to create a [Android Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69706). Please feel free to star it. 

There was a suggestions to use `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` but because there is no way to get a failure it would be hard to try and use `Hardware` and then fall back. I will update my post and keep pinging Google about it

Answer (score 0):

`"setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)"` can work well,but emoji can't when you rotate your canvas if turning off hardware acceleration. hope it helps.